# Erlang Install on i368-pc-sollaris2.10 issues

Tags: c++, gcc, erlang, rabbitmq, solaris

I am running into an issue with an Erlang install on our Unix machine (Solaris 10).

Erlang version: R16B03
OS: Solaris 10
GCC: 4.8.2

I am following the steps listed on the official install page:

[Erlang Install Instructions](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/HOWTO/INSTALL.md)

I have unpacked the tar file from erlang.org, these are the steps I have followed:

```
export ERL_TOP=<my local directory where tar file was unpacked>/otp_src_R16B03
export DED_LD=gcc #using gcc located at /usr/sfw/bin/gcc
export PATH=/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin/:/bin 
./configure –prefix=<target erlang install directory>
```

Configuration finished with: (I can post the entire output if necessary)

---

```
*********************************************************************
**********************  APPLICATIONS DISABLED  **********************
*********************************************************************

odbc           : ODBC library - link check failed

*********************************************************************
*********************************************************************
**********************  APPLICATIONS INFORMATION  *******************
*********************************************************************

wx             : wxWidgets not found, wx will NOT be usable

*********************************************************************
*********************************************************************
**********************  DOCUMENTATION INFORMATION  ******************
*********************************************************************

documentation  :
                 fop is missing.
                 Using fakefop to generate placeholder PDF files.

---
```

Then I ran make as instructed in the install instructions

```
gmake #located at /usr/sfw/bin/gmake
```

The error I receive is:

---

```
gcc  -o ../priv/lib/i386-pc-solaris2.10/trace_ip_drv.so ../priv/obj/i386-pc-    solaris2.10/trace_ip_drv.o -lc -lsendfile -ldlpi -ldl -lm   -lsocket -lnsl
Undefined                       first referenced
symbol                             in file
main                                /usr/lib/crt1.o
set_port_control_flags              ../priv/obj/i386-pc-   solaris2.10/trace_ip_drv.o
driver_alloc                        ../priv/obj/i386-pc-solaris2.10/trace_ip_drv.o
driver_alloc_binary                 ../priv/obj/i386-pc-solaris2.10/trace_ip_drv.o
driver_free                         ../priv/obj/i386-pc-solaris2.10/trace_ip_drv.o
driver_select                       ../priv/obj/i386-pc-solaris2.10/trace_ip_drv.o
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to ../priv/lib/i386-pc-solaris2.10/trace_ip_drv.so
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

I looked around..it looks like it has to do with the gcc library on Solaris. Is this an issue with my gcc install where it has unresolved symbols?

I realize I can get pass this by using LDFLAGS=-W1,-x,nodefs where it ignores unresolved symbols. However I need this for the purpose of running RabbitMQ, and I run into other issues when running RabbitMQ when install Erlang this way, so I would like to see what your opinions are.

Thanks,

Comment: Is `gcc  -o ../priv/lib/i386-pc-solaris2.10/trace_ip_drv.so ../priv/obj/i386-pc-    solaris2.10/trace_ip_drv.o -lc -lsendfile -ldlpi -ldl -lm   -lsocket -lnsl` the entire command line of the link statement?  It looks like it's trying to make a shared object from the `-o ...so` output filename argument, but it's missing the `-shared` argument for a shared object.

Comment: thanks: `gcc -shared -o ../priv/lib/i386-pc-solaris2.10/trace_ip_drv.so ../priv/obj/i386-pc-solaris2.10/trace_ip_drv.o -lc -lsendfile -ldlpi -ldl -lm   -lsocket -lnsl`
worked after adding `-shared`. Can anyone explain what the flag does? This make file is from the default erlang install package, I wonder why they are missing `-shared`. They didn't expect the user to use gcc as linker?